# BASH - What does _(){ _|_&}; _ do?

Tags: bash, expansion, brace-expansion

I'm guessing the {} expansion results in something like

```
_() _  _()_&; _
```

but I would appreciate if a BASH guru chimed in and explained those characters chaining actions.

Comment: worse was `:(){:|:&};:` which was even less legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the classic fork bomb: it defines a function named `_` that calls itself twice (once in the foreground and once in the background) and calls it:

```
bomb(){ bomb | bomb &}; bomb
```

---

```
bomb() {
    bomb | bomb&
};

bomb
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb